# How to access multiple data into controller from ng-model angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions"> 

                <label> {{ question.label }}  <span ng-if="question.required == 1">*</span></label>
                <div ng-if="question.type=='text' || question.type=='number'">
                 <div class="span-width clearfix">  
                   <div class="col-sm-6 col-ie-6">
                      <div class="text-input question-txt">
                      <label for="question"> {{question.type | capitalize}} </label>
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle success" ng-show="form.eventQuestion.{{ 'question'+ question.id }}.$valid"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-times-circle error" ng-show="form.eventQuestion.{{ 'question'+ question.id }}.$invalid"></i>
                         <input
                          type="{{question.type}}"
                          name="{{ 'question'+ question.id }}"
                          class="questionGroup"
                          max="{{ (question.type == 'range' || question.type == 'number') ? question.max : ''}}"
                          min="{{ (question.type == 'range' || question.type == 'number') ? question.min : ''}}"
                          step="{{ (question.type == 'range' || question.type == 'number' ) ? question.step : ''}}"
                          id="{{ 'question'+ question.id }}"
                          ng-model="question.answer"
                          placeholder="{{question.placeholder}}"
                          ng-required="question.required == 1"
                          >

                      </div>

                      Answer: {{questionans.answer}}
                    </div> 

                </div>
          </div> <!-- End of input form -->

          </div>
```

How to Access value from view to controller using ng-repeat while checking {{question.answer}} show answer but in controller did not find anything when console set $scope.question please guide why this is happening i have multiple record need to save into database-

Ctrl

```
$http.get('v1/qst/'+ id +'/find/question')
        .then(function(res){
          $scope.questions = res.data.data;

          $scope.questionOptions = [];
          $scope.questionRadio = [];
          angular.forEach($scope.questions, function(value, key){

              if(value.type == 'select') {
                  $scope.questionOptions = value.value.split(/\r?\n/);
              }else if(value.type == 'radio'){
                $scope.questionRadio = value.value.split(/\r?\n/);
              }
          });

        }).catch(function(error){
          console.log("No data found");
        })
```

Comment: There is no `$scope.question` here;  There is, however, `$scope.questions[0].answer`, `$scope.questions[1].answer`, `$scope.questions[2].answer`, etc....

Comment: I also put ng-model="question.answer[$index]" and tried to access console.log($scope.questions[$index]); says undefined

Comment: Is this not possible with one button click?

Comment: That's completely wrong.  the `ng-repeat` **iterates** the `questions` array, and each `question` is an element in the array.  `question.answer[$index]` would imply that `question` itself was an array, with multiple `answer`, but `$index` is the `question` element, not an `answer` element....  If your `ng-model="question.answer"`, then the specific `question` at that element should have an `answer` property, so `$questions[questionIndex].answer` should be populated.  however, `$index` is not a property of `$scope` or the Controller, so you can't use it in a `console.log`...

Comment: if you use `console.log($scope.questions)`, do the individual elements not have an `answer` property?  they should....

Comment: If you can post some sample data, it would be much easier to work with your code...

Comment: Getting Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object ]

Object having {

 id:1,
 question : 'abc',
 answer : '1'
}..


I want to post each data

Comment: Any Idea claies

Comment: I want to know which model get effected bring json for that

suppose that i have four textboxes one which one changes made get those response
current when is set console.log("Qs", $scope.questions[0]); show me first array object it should be shows json which ng-model effected

Comment: You are looking at this the wrong way. The **entire array** is two way bound, and when you add an `answer`, it adds it to the array element (i.e. `$scope.questions[0].answer` is the answer to the first `question`, `[1].answer` would be the second answer, etc..)  You don't get a **separate** `answer` variable.  If you sent the array to the server, it would contain the answers.  You could loop through the array and look for the answers and send just those to the server, if that is what your server needs, or just loop through the array and if `answer` exists, send that element to the server.

Comment: Thank you claies for valuable time i appreciate thank you once again